# firewall-cmd reject destination address

Tags: redhat, firewalld, rhel7

I'm using following:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core) 
# rpm -q firewalld
firewalld-0.3.9-11.el7.noarch
#
```

I'm trying to block specific IP address (10.52.208.220) from reaching it from my system, yet unable to do so:

before:

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
success
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client high-availability http https ssh
  ports: 5666/tcp 3306/tcp 5900/tcp 9001/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

# ping -c1 wcmisdlin01
PING wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org (10.52.208.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org (10.52.208.220): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.379 ms

--- wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.379/0.379/0.379/0.000 ms
#
```

after:

```
# firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.52.208.220" protocol value="icmp" reject'
success
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client high-availability http https ssh
  ports: 5666/tcp 3306/tcp 5900/tcp 9001/tcp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
    rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.52.208.220" protocol value="icmp" reject

# ping -c1 wcmisdlin01
PING wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org (10.52.208.220) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org (10.52.208.220): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.266 ms

--- wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.266/0.266/0.266/0.000 ms
#
```

`IPTABLES(8) - iptables/ip6tables — administration tool for IPv4/IPv6 packet filtering and NAT`

```
# iptables --list IN_public_deny
Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     icmp --  anywhere             wcmisdlin01.uftmasterad.org  ctstate NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
#
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `IN_public_deny` sounds like it is for *inbound* packets, e.g. from the remote system to your system. This would therefore not block a outgoing connection from your system to the host in question, as the response from the blocked host would be shuffled through the connection state created by the outgoing packet.

Comment: @thrig that's what I thought too, that's why I included in my question, but then again chain can be named differently, the question is how to make it work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On inspection of the full `iptables -n --list` output, `IN_public_deny` is (eventually) called from the `INPUT` chain, which has nothing to do with packets sent from the system to the thus undenied host; those packets are instead routed through the `OUTPUT` chain (or possibly `FORWARD` if the firewall is a router or bridge between the source and destination). `firewalld.richlanguage(5)` does not appear to offer any means of specifying that the rule must go onto the `OUTPUT` (or `FORWARD`) chain, so the "last resort" option of a direct rule appears to be one solution.

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT_direct 0 -p icmp -d 10.52.208.220 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

(Though usually I prefer to DROP (and possibly LOG with rate limiting) instead of sending ICMP rejects, as if the host-to-be-blocked is going nuts, throwing ICMP response packets to it back onto a burdened network can make things go from bad to worse...)